# How to test Selectors on proxy-objects in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance, respondstoselector

Is there any way to test selectors/methods when all you have is a proxy object?

```
/* Proxy which may forward
 * the method to some other object */ 
id proxy = [UINavigationBar appearance];

/* This condition returns FALSE
 * despite the fact that the method would have otherwise been
 * successfully executed at its destination */
if([proxy respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]){
    [proxy setBarTintColor:color];
}
```

Comment: @maddy that's why I'm trying to find a way to test whether the method call will be successful before calling it -- rather than having the logic based on the OS version..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you cannot.

The methods suggested by other answers will break easily, here's an example:

- `UINavigationBar` instances respond to selector `setTranslucent:`
- However `setTranslucent:` is not tagged with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` in the header file

Therefore the following code

```
if([[UINavigationBar class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setTranslucent:)]) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]; // BUM!
}
```

will result in a crash.

The only information about which selectors conform to `UIAppearance` seems to be the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` macro, which is stripped at compile-time.

A runtime check doesn't look to be feasible.

---

For the sake of completeness, here's an **awful** (but practical) way of doing it.

```
@try {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    if ([exception.name isEqualToString:@"NSInvalidArgumentException"])
        NSLog(@"Woops");
    else
        @throw;
}
```

However, this is very fragile since there's no guarantee that you're catching only the case in which the selector doesn't conform to `UIAppearance`.

Comment: Ok, you did point out that it's an awful suggestion, but its fine without the exception block. Don't swallow exceptions - let it crash and fail fast and let the developer know that it doesn't work. It's the next best thing for this situation than the compiler telling the developer it doesn't work.

Comment: Same thing I wrote under you answer. The point is to perform a runtime check, not to detect which methods are supported by the proxy. For that we have the documentation and the headers.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet seems to be

1. Make sure that the property in question is defined with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` in the header.
2. In the code test against the class `UINavigationBar` itself rather than its appearance

   ```
    if ([(some UINavigationBar object) respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)])...
   ```

or, as another answer suggests,

```
if ([UINavigationBar.class instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)])...
```

While theoretically `proxy` is an object of a different class, the appearance proxy seems to be automatically generated by Apple from methods labeled as `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`. As the comment in `UIAppearance.h` states:

> To participate in the appearance proxy API, tag your appearance property selectors in your header with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.

This method will break if you implement it for a property that was available through appearance proxy in the old version of iOS but was removed from the proxy later. Exactly one such example is documented in the same file:

> On iOS7 ... the `tintColor` is now disallowed with the appearance proxy.

So you do need to test for rare cases to make sure the code is not broken by the new iOS, but you're still free of having to code the version numbers manually.